# Documentation for unexpected scope behaviour

Tags: python, scope, documentation

I hit a scoping issue today that initially surprised me. It can be readily demonstrated by the following:

```
def scope():
    x = 1
    def working():
        print x
    def broken():
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    working()
    broken()


Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
...
>>> scope()
1
--Return--
> <stdin>(6)broken()->None
(Pdb) x
*** NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 10 2016, 08:21:44)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def scope():
...
>>> scope()
1
--Return--
> <stdin>(6)broken()->None
(Pdb) x
*** NameError: name 'x' is not defined
(Pdb)
```

So it appears a scope will only contain outer-scope values if there's an explicit reference to them *at compilation time*. This is certainly what appears to happen when looking at the bytecode:

```
  6           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Is this an artifact of how Python differentiates between outer & inner scope references by examining the function for bindings?

This does not appear to be explained by the [Python scoping rules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces):

> Although **scopes are determined statically**, they are used dynamically. At **any time during execution**, there are at least three nested scopes whose namespaces are directly accessible:
>
> - the innermost scope, which is searched first, contains the local names
> - the scopes of any enclosing functions, which are searched starting with the nearest enclosing scope, contains non-local, but also non-global names

What I'm trying to understand is the conflict between the two highlighted parts above: scopes are static but the promise of what names are accessible doesn't seem to be upheld.

Specifically, what I'm looking for is official documentation of this explicit behaviour.

Comment: An inner scope doesn't contain an outer-scope object, but it can read it if it's not shadowed by an object with the same name in an inner scope. For details, please see [Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Comment: Yes, binding (assignment) in a function makes a variable local to that function, if there's no `global` or `nonlocal` statement declaring it otherwise. This is indeed done statically at compile time. In `working()` Python knows `x` is not local so loads it with the `LOAD_GLOBAL` opcode (which you can see by disassembling with the `dis` module).

Comment: @PM2Ring I noticed this when I set a `pdb` breakpoint in the inner function and tried to inspect the outer scope. I wasn't shadowing any object but still couldn't "read" outer scope objects. It's the necessity for the name to be present at compile time that is confusing, this isn't a shadowing issue.

Comment: @kindall Cheers but i'd like to confirm if this is documented behaviour or an artifact of CPython's implementation.

Comment: It's documented. https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/executionmodel.html - ”If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block”

Comment: @kindall But the same page says "If the definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks contained within the defining one, unless a contained block introduces a different binding for the name." There's a distinction between local and available.

Comment: @PM2Ring "If the definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks contained within the defining one" `outer` is a function block, `inner` is a function block contained within it, why isn't the scope of `outer` extending to `inner` as described?

Comment: Why don't you use your **actual** code, the `locals` behaviour is *different* from your actual issue. Just try printing `locals()['x']` in the `working` function.

Comment: `x` is not in `locals` within a function as it is not a local variable in that scope. As for the `pdb.set_trace()` within a function - I cannot repeat the name error and thus am unable to reproduce this issue.

Comment: How exactly were you running this? I have tried copying it into a standard interpreter, running as a script, running in iPython console, importing the functions and running from an interpreter, and in all those cases `x` is visible to the interpreter and is `1`. I'm running on macOS 10.12, and have tried python 3.5.0 and python 2.7.10. Are you sure you saw what you thought you saw?

Comment: @daphtdazz Sorry, I simplified it to the point where it was no longer a problem. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the specification of how this works is covered by the introducing [PEP227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/) (for python 2.1!). Key parts:

> The Python 2.0 definition specifies exactly three namespaces ... the local namespace, the global namespace,
>       and the builtin namespace.  According to this definition, if a
>       function A is defined within a function B, the names bound in B
>       are not visible in A.  The proposal changes the rules so that
>       names bound in B are visible in A (unless A contains a name
>       binding that hides the binding in B).
>
> ...
>
> *If a name is used within** a code block, but it is not bound there
>       and is not declared global, the use is treated as a reference to
>       the nearest enclosing function region.
>
> ...
>
> An analogous function [*to locals() and globals()*] will not be provided for nested scopes. Under this proposal, it will not be possible to gain dictionary-style access to all visible scopes.

* emphasised bit being the key bit: Your variable has not been used within a code block, so therefore there is nothing to treat as a reference to the enclosing function.

Furthermore, `pdb` is running dynamically and the [`default` (source code link)](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pdb.py#l770) action when no command has been specified uses `exec` with `locals` and `globals` from the frame. Therefore the only variables available to it are `locals()` and `globals()` of the frame being inspected, which as indicated do not include captured variables from enclosing frames.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is not local to `broken` ("local" meaning assigned inside the function), so it won't show up in `locals()`.

However, you can access objects from the outer scope if they are not shadowed by a local, so you can access it in `working`.

Comment: My bad, the `locals()` example was incorrect and not indicative of the problem as I thought. I've updated the question.